# C# Injecting Specific Item from appSettings.json at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

How can I inject a specific setting (of possibly many) from an array appSettings.json in a C# .NET Core Web API, based on a runtime input value?

appSettings.json:

```
{
  "SettingProfiles": [
    { 
      "Name": "Profile1",
      "SettingA": "SettingAValue1",
      "SettingB": "SettingBValue1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Profile2",
      "SettingA": "SettingAValue2",
      "SettingB": "SettingBValue2"
    }
    ...
}
```

Settings Classes:

```
public class Settings {
    public List<SettingsProfile> SettingsProfiles { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsProfile {
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public string SettingA { get; set; };
    public string SettingB { get; set; };
}
```

Service class:

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private readonly SettingsProfile _Profile;
    
    public MyService(SettingsProfile profile) {
        _Profile = profile;
    }

    public void DoStuff() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Setting A: {_SettingsProfile.SettingA}, Setting B: {_SettingsProfile.SettingB}")
    }
}
```

The user will enter the setting name they want to apply.  I am unsure how to do this if the service is configured in Startup.cs, at which point I don't yet have the setting to use.

I am understanding that "newing" the service would be bad practice, although that's the only way I can figure out how to make it work:

```
public class MyController {

   private readonly Settings _Settings;

   public MyController(Settings settings) {
       _Settings = settings;
   }

   public IActionResult DoStuff(profileName) {
       SettingsProfile profile = _Settings.Where(profile => profile.Name == profileName);
       MyService service = new Service(profile);
   }
}
```

I'm obviously missing something, but I've been watching YouTube videos on Dependency Injections and reading StackOverflow until my eyes bleed, and haven't figured it out yet. Can someone help me with a pattern that I should be following?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you don't just inject the parent `Settings` class, and simply do `Settings.SettingProfiles.Single(x => x.Name == selectedName);`  Am I missing something?

Comment: You’re not. I could do that, and it’s probably better than what I have above, but I feel like then I am injecting extraneous information into the class, which is bad practice, is it not?

Comment: Is the idea that the selected setting name is already available (stored in the backend)?  Or rather that the user is literally using a combo box to select it in the UI?  What means are you using to obtain the selected setting name?  Is it based on an HTTP request (perhaps a JWT token)?

Comment: You can use a middleware that intecepts your parameter and set your value in `context.item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I think it should work.
It will be a lot cleaner if you use another pattern: Factory.

```cs
interface ISettingServiceFactory{
 MyService GetService(string profileName);
}
class SettingServiceFactory: ISettingServiceFactory
{
  MyService GetService(string profileName){

  }
}
```

Now you can implement `GetService` in two ways.

The first one is by creating new as you did in the controller and is not that bad as this is the purpose of the factory. In this way you kind of move that logic somewhere else.

A second one would be a bit uglier but something like this

```cs
interface ISettingServiceFactory{
 MyService GetService(string profileName);
 void SetCurrentProfile(SettingsProfile profile);
}

class SettingServiceFactory: ISettingServiceFactory
{
private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
private Settings _Settings;
  public SettingServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,Settings settings){
_serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
_Settings = settings;
}
  MyService GetService(string profileName){
   var service = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
   var profile = _Settings.Where(profile => profile.Name == profileName);
   service.SetCurrentProfile(profile);
   return service;
  }
}
```

This second approach would be useful only if the implementation of `MyService` has a lot of other dependencies by itself and if you want to avoid `new` at any cost.

In both cases you will inject the factory in the controller

```cs
 public MyController(ISettingServiceFactory settingServiceFactory) {
        _settingServiceFactory= settingServiceFactory;
    }

public IActionResult DoStuff(profileName) {
       MyService service = _settingServiceFactory.GetService(profileName)
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. The first approach is what I was looking for!